# Modern equivalent of DCMPLX?

Tags: fortran

Using the well-known [`DCMPLX`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/DCMPLX.html) intrinsic function, `gfortran -g -std=f2008 -Wall -Wextra -O2` returns `Warning: The intrinsic 'dcmplx' at (1) is not included in the selected standard but a GNU Fortran extension and 'dcmplx' will be treated as if declared EXTERNAL.  Use an appropriate -std=* option or define -fall-intrinsics to allow this intrinsic`.  Is there a modern, cross-compiler way of manipulating double precision complex numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
CMPLX(X, Y, kind=REAL64)
```

To use `REAL64`, you need to import the module `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV`.

This is defined in section `13.7.36` in the Fortran 2008 Standard (Draft).

Comment: No! Please don't use `kind=8`! Use `ISO_Fortran_env` and parameters like `REAL64`, or something like `selected_real_kind()`... Otherwise, your code isn't portable.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt Thanks for reminding me... My mind was in quick-code-mode.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to convert to the double precision kind, whatever kind number it has, use

```
cmplx(real_part, imaginary_part, kind=kind(1.0d0))
```

Normally you should store the kind number in a named constant. If you actually do not want a double precision, but a fixed storage size, use named constants from the module `iso_fortran_env`, or the older method of specifing precision with `selected_real_kind()`.